# difference between binary queue and sorted queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, priority-queue

I'm trying to understand the difference between binary queues and sorted queues. I know that the sorted priority queue implements the priority queue interface by maintaining a sorted vector. But what exactly does a binary queue do?

So for example, if i were trying to code this what would be the difference?

```
//Assumes that all elements in the priority queue are out of order.
//             Reorder the data so that the PQ invariant is restored.
//Runtime: O(n log n)
template<typename TYPE, typename COMP_FUNCTOR>
void SortedPQ<TYPE, COMP_FUNCTOR>::updatePriorities() {
    //Implementation here
}

//Assumes that all elements in the priority queue are out of order.
//             Reorder the data so that the PQ invariant is restored.
 //Runtime: O(n)
template<typename TYPE, typename COMP_FUNCTOR>
void BinaryPQ<TYPE, COMP_FUNCTOR>::updatePriorities() {
    //Implementation here
}
```